# Changing default palette opens plotting window - is there a way to suppress it?

Tags: r, color-palette

When changing the color palette in R:

```
palette(c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

An empty window pops-up. Read the `help(palette)` but didn't find any mention there. Is there a way to suppress this behaviour and change the palette silently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour has changed in R 4.0.0.

So if you are using R 4.0.0. or above changing the default palette colors:

```
palette(c("red", "green", "blue"))
```

will no longer open an empty graphics device window.

Answer (score 1):

The `palette` function needs to have a device to which it applies. If you want to avoid seeing an interactive graphics window appear, you will need to have a file device open at the time of the call. So this raises the question: "What were you hoping to do with this?"

```
png()
palette(rainbow(6))
palette()
#[1] "red"     "yellow"  "green"   "cyan"    "blue"    "magenta"
mypal <- palette()
dev.off()  # no graphics device for that palette anymore
mypal   # the state of that palette is now available.
#[1] "red"     "yellow"  "green"   "cyan"    "blue"    "magenta"
```

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer. My goal was to put this inside my "interactive use config" of R to overwrite default color numbers. I noticed that when I close that window the new `palette()` settings remain. So was a bit puzzled why the window had to open in the first place.

Comment: It actually still is puzzling to me. But I found that `palette(colors);invisible(dev.off())` works so will use that for now.